# Implementing Simultaneous OAuth Grant Types

Tags: oauth, asp.net-identity, owin

Currently trying to figure out a solution for ASP Identity v3's lack of multiple identity support. The reason why I need to find this solution is because we have a "Partner" website that is supposed to authenticate with a custom API. After that token is received, whoever the "User" is will then login to the API to complete their claims-based actions. But multiple tokens cannot be given to one identity.

Came across OAuth 2 grant types. I was wondering if it was possible to implement multiple grant types, so that I can allow the "Partner" site and "User" to authenticate separately.

If it seems like I'm missing some fundamental understanding of what I'm trying to do, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

From: https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified

OAuth 2 provides several "grant types" for different use cases. The grant types defined are:

```
Authorization Code for apps running on a web server
Implicit for browser-based or mobile apps
Password for logging in with a username and password
Client credentials for application access
```